# leaflet popup auto close upon api call

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet to show my markers into google map. everything works fine. My markers are being loaded by an api call in every 10 secs. if i click on any markers a popup window is open. But it disappeared as soon as the api is called again. I have tried so far as follows:

```js
var infoWindow_content = "<h3>Hello world</h3>";
var theMarker = L.marker([devices[x].lat, devices[x].lng], {
                            icon: customicon,
                            rotationAngle: devices[x].angle
                        }).on('click', markerOnClick).addTo(map).bindPopup(infoWindow_content, {
                            autoPan: true,
                            autoClose:false,
                            closeOnClick:false,
                            
                        });
```

is there anyway to keep the popup window open even the marker gets reloaded? In that case is the popup window follow marker movement? thanks in advance

Comment: Do not recreate the marker. Move it with `.setLatLng()` instead.

Comment: hello... thanks for your prompt reply. can u pls give me an example. i am totally stuck